# Twig/Timber/ACF how to output only categories assigned to item

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have a page built in Timber/Twig (WordPress) using ACF.
It outputs a list of people using an ACF repeater field, and I need to filter these using categories, which are meant to be set in one of the fields (using taxonomy as its type) inside the repeater.

The problem I am having is that all of the categories are being output, rather than the ones which are selected via an ACF checkbox for each person.

Here is my code:

```
{% for item in post.meta('projectname_network') %}

    {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}

        <div class="{% for category in post.terms('category') %}{{ category.slug }} {% endfor %} portfolio-item network-headshot col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
            <div class="network-header" id="network{{ counter ~ item.title }}">
                        
                {% for category in post.terms('category') %}
                    {{ category.slug }}
                {% endfor %}
                        
                <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{ counter ~ item.title }}" aria-controls="modal{{ counter ~ item.title }}">
                    other content goes here
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am outputting the categories as class names for the bootstrap filter, but have also included them as text, so I can more easily see what's being output.

I know that right now I am basically saying include all categories from the post, or all categories that exist, but that's the nearest I've got to displaying what I need.

If I put:

```
{% for category in projectname_category %}
    {{ category.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

then nothing is output (projectname_category is the name of the ACF category field).

I'm just not sure of the correct syntax to use here, as ACF and Timber docs don't seem to cover this use case.

Comment: It was easier than I thought. I found the answer here: 
https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-user/#slug

{% for slug, category in item.my_category %}{{ category.slug }} {% endfor %}

Comment: "easier than I thought" "I found the answer in the docs" — the sweet words an open source dev can ever hear!!!